# Demonstrate that $B$ is a base in the following linear space...

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let be $(V,+, \cdot, R )$ a real linear space, $dim_RV=n$, $T$ an
>   endomorphism and let $x \in V $ such that $T^n(x)=\theta$,
>   $T^{n-1}(x)\neq \theta$.  Demonstrate that $B=(x, T(x),T^2(x),...,
> T^{n-1}(x))$ forms a base in $V$.

I have no idea how to begin even, I've solved exercises with determining whether X is a base only working with vectors, but this is a different case, here linear transformations are involved. Can you please help me understand how should I solve it, if it's possible ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there is a linear dependency 
$$ \tag1a_0x+a_1T(x)+a_2T^2(x)+\ldots +a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(x)=0$$
and not all $a_i$ are zero. Let $k$ be minimal index with $a_k\ne0$.
Apply $T^{n-k-1}$ to equation $(1)$ to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean by "apply $T^{n-k-1}$"?

Comment: @JohnG. Consider $T^{n-k-1}(a_0x+\ldots+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(x))$

Comment: Sorry but I still do not understand your explanation